# Images Form a Topology?

Tags: general-topology

I have a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ between two topological spaces $(X,\mathcal{T}_1)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T}_2)$ that is $\mathcal{T}_1$-$\mathcal{T}_2$ continuous, and I'm asked to determine if the set of images {$f(V):V\in \mathcal{T}_1$} is a topology on $Y$.  I've been wracking my brain on this one for days, and can't find a counterexample, but can't find a formal proof either.  Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The result is not true in general.

Let $X=(0,1)$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}$. Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be the inclusion map. For $\{F(V):V\in\mathcal{T}_{1}\}$ to be a topology on $\mathbb{R}$, we need $\mathbb{R}\in \{f(V):V\in\mathcal{T}_{1}\}$, which we don't have.

Comment: However, if $f$ is onto, the statement is true.

Comment: @lattice.  For the inclusion map or in general?

Comment: I guess I'm stuck on the terminology of "a topology on $Y$".  So that means that $Y$ HAS to be the set?  I guess I am confused, cause I'm thinking that ${{0},{1},{0,1},\emptyset$ is a topology on \mathbb{R}, but I guess it's more of a subspace topology, is that fair?

Comment: @Craig.  Y is a set.  A topology for Y  is a subset of the power set of Y.  The crammed together and lacking a bracket set you defined is not a topology for R.  Why?

Comment: Cause R's not it in the set itself.  I guess I'm stuck on whether "a topology on Y" necessarily means Y is in the set, or whether it could also mean subsets of Y that do not necessarily include Y. (e.g., like {{0},\emptyset} is a topology, and 0 and the emptyset are both subsets of Y).  I'm thinking a "topology on Y" strictly means the Y is the largest open subset in our topology.

Comment: @Craig.  Read the definition of a topology T_S, for a set S.  You ' ll find that both S and emptyset are in T_S.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I believe this should be true for any continuous and onto map $f$, if the sets $f(V)$ are the open sets of the new topology $\mathcal{T}_3$. In this case, we have $\emptyset=f(\emptyset)$, $Y=f(X)$, $\cup_i f(V_i)=f(\cup_i V_i)$ and $f(U)\cap f(V)=f(U\cap V)$. So all the requirements for $\mathcal{T}_3$ to be a topology on $Y$ follow from the fact that $\mathcal{T}_1$ is a topology on $X$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I was too late to edit my post. Actually, the above shows that we don't even need $\mathcal{T}_2$ or the continuity of $f$ into this space. So a correct statement should be: Given any map $f:X\to Y$ where $X$ is a topological space, the sets $f(V)$ for $V\subset X$ open define (as open sets in $im(f)$) a topology on $im(f)$.

Comment: @lattice.  See my answer where I give an counter example and a proposition.

Answer (score 1):

If f:X -> Y is a continuous surjection, then T = { f(U) | U open }
may not be a topology for Y.  Example:

X = [0,2],  Y = S^1,  f(x) = (sin pi.x, cos pi.x)
[0,1) and (1,2] are open, so f([0,1}) cap f((1,2]) = {(0,1)}
should be open but there is no open U for which f(U) is a
singleton.

However if f is a bijection, then T is a topology for Y.
The continuity of f is unimportant.  Only that X is a
topological space and f is a bijection.

Exercise.  If f is an injection, show f(A cap B) = f(A) cap f(B).

---